# Wordpress - Custom Post Type with 3 input fields and

Tags: php, wordpress, web, content-management-system

I am trying to modify wordpress for my needs:
I want a custom post type (well, thats basically easy), but instead of only 1 article section it should have three or more of them, divided by  tags. All the div-tags should have one class in common (for example class="article"). The other classes should able to be assigned specifically, that means i'd like to have a little box beneath each of the article input fields, in which I can select different classes for each of the fields.
I have googeled a lot and didn't find anything. Are there any tutorials/blogposts on this or do you know any advice?
Thanks in advance,
JBG

Answer (score 1):

hi you can create custom filed with http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

Comment: Yep, I already found that, but I need an elegant solution as it may be used for future customers. But thanks anyway ;)